# CSV text files loading error / crash in QGIS 2.18.8

Tags: qgis, layers, csv, text

I got a problem when I try to load tab-separated text files in the "Create a layer from the delimited text file" tab (that one with de comma symbol). After normally selecting the X and Y fields and clicking OK, the reference coordinate system (SRC) selector screen appears, then the program closes by itself. I had uploaded more than a hundred of this type of file by the same procedure in the previous version of QGIS (2.14 Essen) and have no problem, but since I updated to version 2.18.8 (Las Palmas) I can not load any files or .CSV type.

Do anyone knows what's happening? Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug in 2.18.8 : [issues.qgis.org/issues/16600#change-79959](http://issues.qgis.org/issues/16600#change-79959) 
Install/use a version <> 2.18.8

Comment: Do you know if there's any hopes that this will be corrected in osgeo4w, or do we have to rollback for one month until the new version?

Comment: The bug is also affecting loading Spatialite data when done from the Browser Panel. Inserting data using the toolbar doesn't seem affected.

Answer (score 1):

This was corrected in version 2.18.9, you can now update Qgis either with the standalone version or with osgeo4w.