# QGIS crashes while reading csv data

Tags: qgis, python

I have added delimited text layer from a csv with "watch file" option checked in and I want to update the mapcanvas every five second the program always crashes. I have attached the sample python script.

```
import time

while True:

    time.sleep(5)

    iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: if on QGIS 2.18.8 there is bug with csv files https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241575/csv-text-files-loading-error-crash-in-qgis-2-18-8

Comment: Please use the code format `{}` when posting your question. Make sure the indentation is correct after pasting your code.

Comment: how to use code format... im new to gis stack exchange

Comment: After pasting your code into your question, select the code and use `{}` in the menu bar to format the code.